# Error validating CMS signature

Tags: swift, openssl, cryptography, digital-signature, pkcs#7

For the past 2 weeks I've been banging my head against a wall trying to create and validate CMS signatures in Swift 4 using OpenSSL.  My code is ultimately destined to be run on Linux, so I can't use the macOS Security framework.  I *believe* I have finally gotten CMS signature creation working properly.  My code for that looks like this:

```
let testBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))

guard let textUrl = testBundle.url(forResource: "test_message", withExtension: "txt"),
    let signingKeyUrl = testBundle.url(forResource: "signing_key", withExtension: "pem"),
    let signingCertUrl = testBundle.url(forResource: "signing_cert", withExtension: "pem") else {
        exit(1)
}

let certFileObject = signingCertUrl.path.withCString { filePtr in
    return fopen(filePtr, "rb")
}
defer {
    fclose(certFileObject)
}

let keyFileObject = signingKeyUrl.path.withCString { filePtr in
    return fopen(filePtr, "rb")
}
defer {
    fclose(keyFileObject)
}

guard let key = PEM_read_PrivateKey(keyFileObject, nil, nil, nil),
    let cert = PEM_read_X509(certFileObject, nil, nil, nil) else {
        exit(1)
}

OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers()
OpenSSL_add_all_digests()
OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_conf()

guard let textData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: textUrl.path) else {
    exit(1)
}

guard let textBIO = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()) else {
    print("Unable to create textBIO")
    exit(1)
}

_ = textData.withUnsafeBytes({dataBytes in
    BIO_write(textBIO, dataBytes, Int32(textData.count))
})

guard let cms = CMS_sign(cert, key, nil, textBIO, UInt32(CMS_BINARY)) else {
    exit(1)
}
```

When I debug this code, I see that the `cms` object is being set after the `CMS_sign` call, so I believe that the signature was generated properly.  Right after this, I'm trying to validate the signature I just created.  That code looks like this:

```
 let store = X509_STORE_new()
 X509_STORE_add_cert(store, cert)

 let outBIO = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem())
 let result = CMS_verify(cms, nil, store, nil, outBIO, 0)
 print("result : \(result)")

 if result != 1 {
     let errorCode: UInt = ERR_get_error()
     print("ERROR : \(String(format: "%2X", errorCode))")
 }
```

When I run this code, however, `result` == 0, indicating an error.  The error code that OpenSSL is returning is `0x2E099064`.  I ran this command:

```
openssl errstr 0x2E099064
```

Which gave me this info about the error:

> error:2E099064:CMS routines:func(153):reason(100)

After a bit more digging, I *think* that the error corresponds to PKCS7_R_DECRYPTED_KEY_IS_WRONG_LENGTH.  I got that from the [pkcs7.h file here.](http://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/openssl/1.0.1c/crypto_2pkcs7_2pkcs7_8h_source.html#l00405)  I'm not 100% that this is the correct error message, however.

My question is, why is my signature validation failing?  I'm using the exact same certificate to validate the signature.  All of this code is inline, so nothing is getting lost anywhere.  Can any of you give me an idea where things are going wrong?

Comment: Module 0x2E=46 is CMS not PKCS7; in cms.h CMS_F_CMS_SIGNERINFO_VERIFY_CERT=153 and CMS_R_CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_ERROR=100. I'm surprised commandline `errstr` didn't decode this for you; mine does, except way back in 0.9.8. Is the signing cert self-signed or CA-issued? If the latter you must put its full chain (to anchor) in `store` since you _didn't_ put any chain certs in the message when signing. Does it have the correct 'purpose' (KeyUsage and ExtendedKeyUsage)? Note signing does not verify the cert, since it doesn't rely on the publickey.

Comment: Are you using a self-generated cert? Does your cert have a subject key identifier extension?

Comment: The cert is self-signed.  I’ll have to check what extensions it has set on it.  Does OpenSSL check the key usage extension by default?

Comment: How did you generate the cert?

Comment: (1) it looks like cms_signerinfo_verify_cert does not modify the default X509_verify_cert logic, in which case IME KU and EKU are optional but if present must be correct. But X509_verify_cert has gone through significant changes over the years and version may matter. (2) this error code has 'extra' data containing the verify-error string; I don't know if `ERR_print_errors_fp(somefp)` will work in Swift but if not `ERR_print_erors(tempmembio)` and then print the bio contents should.

Comment: Okay, so I ran ERR_print_errors on my BIO and got this error: "cms_.c:5812:Verify error:unable to get local issuer certificate".  It's a self-signed cert, so I thought putting it in the X509_Store is sufficient.  Am I wrong about that?

Comment: After MUCH troubleshooting, it looks as though it may be an error in the certificate structure.  The cert validates properly, and I can view the details with no issue.  But, if I generate a new cert and signing key, everything works fine.  That particular cert fails every time, though.  Thanks for your troubleshooting advice!!

Comment: I'm attempting to do the same thing here using an Apple Developer certificate but I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS when running CMS_sign. What distribution of OpenSSL are you using?