# Crash while creating CMS signature on XML data

Tags: swift, openssl, cryptography, digital-signature, pkcs#7

I have been trying to several days to CMS sign some XML text in Swift 5 using OpenSSL. When running CMS_sign I get: **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x65636e6575716573)** . The weird part about this is sometimes this crash occurs and sometimes it doesn't with the exact same setup:

```
 func signData() -> String {
        let signedCertUrl = getfileData(filename: "finalcert", withExtension: "crt")!
        let privateKeyUrl = getfileData(filename: "finalprivatekey", withExtension: "key")!
        
        let signCertObject = signedCertUrl.path.withCString { filePtr in
            return fopen(filePtr, "rb")
        }
        defer {
             fclose(signCertObject)
        }
        let privateKeyObject = privateKeyUrl.path.withCString { filePtr in
            return fopen(filePtr, "rb")
        }
        defer {
             fclose(privateKeyObject)
        }
        
       let key = PEM_read_PrivateKey(privateKeyObject, nil, nil, nil)
       let cert = PEM_read_X509(signCertObject, nil, nil, nil)
 
        OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers()
        OpenSSL_add_all_digests()
        OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()
        ERR_load_CRYPTO_strings()
        SSL_load_error_strings()
        
        let textData = xmlData.data(using: .utf8)!
        guard let textBIO = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()) else {
            print("Unable to create textBIO")
            exit(1)
        }
        _ = textData.withUnsafeBytes({dataBytes in
            BIO_write(textBIO, dataBytes.baseAddress!, Int32(textData.count))
        })
        guard let cms = CMS_sign(cert, key, nil, textBIO, UInt32(CMS_STREAM)) else {
            exit(1)
        }
        
        guard let bios = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()) else {
            exit(1)
        }
        
        SMIME_write_CMS(bios, cms, textBIO, CMS_NOATTR)
        
        
        let written = BIO_number_written(bios)
        var buffer: [Int8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: Int(written) + 1)
        let finalXml = buffer.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { buf -> String in
            BIO_read(bios, buf.baseAddress, Int32(written))
            return String(validatingUTF8: buf.baseAddress!) ?? "Unknown"
        }
        
        return finalXml
    }
```

I'm using the same idea done here: [Error validating CMS signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49889256/error-validating-cms-signature)
 but I cannot produce a consistent result. The certificate I am using is an Apple Developer certificate which I ran openssl commands to get the cert and private key and put the file in the Xcode project. I need to run openssl at runtime during the app based on changes of user generated XML text.

Output from the main-thread after crash:

```
OpenSSL`CMS_sign:
    0x103a18bbc <+0>:   stp    x24, x23, [sp, #-0x40]!
    0x103a18bc0 <+4>:   stp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x10]
    0x103a18bc4 <+8>:   stp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x20]
    0x103a18bc8 <+12>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
    0x103a18bcc <+16>:  add    x29, sp, #0x30            ; =0x30 
    0x103a18bd0 <+20>:  mov    x20, x4
    0x103a18bd4 <+24>:  mov    x21, x3
    0x103a18bd8 <+28>:  mov    x22, x2
    0x103a18bdc <+32>:  mov    x23, x1
    0x103a18be0 <+36>:  mov    x24, x0
    0x103a18be4 <+40>:  bl     0x4c35c                   ; CMS_ContentInfo_new
    0x103a18be8 <+44>:  mov    x19, x0
    0x103a18bec <+48>:  cbz    x0, 0x50cb4               ; <+248>
    0x103a18bf0 <+52>:  mov    x0, x19
    0x103a18bf4 <+56>:  bl     0x4e010                   ; CMS_SignedData_init
    0x103a18bf8 <+60>:  cbz    w0, 0x50cb4               ; <+248>
    0x103a18bfc <+64>:  tbz    w20, #0x13, 0x50c18       ; <+92>
    0x103a18c00 <+68>:  mov    w0, #0x313
    0x103a18c04 <+72>:  bl     0xb8dc0                   ; OBJ_nid2obj
    0x103a18c08 <+76>:  mov    x1, x0
    0x103a18c0c <+80>:  mov    x0, x19
    0x103a18c10 <+84>:  bl     0x4cbe0                   ; CMS_set1_eContentType
    0x103a18c14 <+88>:  cbz    w0, 0x50cd0               ; <+276>
    0x103a18c18 <+92>:  cbz    x23, 0x50c38              ; <+124>
    0x103a18c1c <+96>:  mov    x0, x19
    0x103a18c20 <+100>: mov    x1, x24
    0x103a18c24 <+104>: mov    x2, x23
    0x103a18c28 <+108>: mov    x3, #0x0
    0x103a18c2c <+112>: mov    x4, x20
    0x103a18c30 <+116>: bl     0x4e1fc                   ; CMS_add1_signer
->  0x103a18c34 <+120>: cbz    x0, 0x50cf4               ; <+312>
    0x103a18c38 <+124>: mov    x0, x22
    0x103a18c3c <+128>: bl     0xeefe0                   ; OPENSSL_sk_num
    0x103a18c40 <+132>: cmp    w0, #0x1                  ; =0x1 
    0x103a18c44 <+136>: b.lt   0x50c7c                   ; <+192>
    0x103a18c48 <+140>: mov    w23, #0x0
    0x103a18c4c <+144>: mov    x0, x22
    0x103a18c50 <+148>: mov    x1, x23
    0x103a18c54 <+152>: bl     0xeeff4                   ; OPENSSL_sk_value
    0x103a18c58 <+156>: mov    x1, x0
    0x103a18c5c <+160>: mov    x0, x19
    0x103a18c60 <+164>: bl     0x4d144                   ; CMS_add1_cert
    0x103a18c64 <+168>: cbz    w0, 0x50cb4               ; <+248>
    0x103a18c68 <+172>: add    w23, w23, #0x1            ; =0x1 
    0x103a18c6c <+176>: mov    x0, x22
    0x103a18c70 <+180>: bl     0xeefe0                   ; OPENSSL_sk_num
    0x103a18c74 <+184>: cmp    w23, w0
    0x103a18c78 <+188>: b.lt   0x50c4c                   ; <+144>
    0x103a18c7c <+192>: tbnz   w20, #0x6, 0x50c8c        ; <+208>
    0x103a18c80 <+196>: mov    x0, x19
    0x103a18c84 <+200>: mov    w1, #0x0
    0x103a18c88 <+204>: bl     0x4c3d4                   ; CMS_set_detached
    0x103a18c8c <+208>: mov    w8, #0x5000
    0x103a18c90 <+212>: tst    w20, w8
    0x103a18c94 <+216>: b.ne   0x50cdc                   ; <+288>
    0x103a18c98 <+220>: mov    x0, x19
    0x103a18c9c <+224>: mov    x1, x21
    0x103a18ca0 <+228>: mov    x2, #0x0
    0x103a18ca4 <+232>: mov    x3, x20
    0x103a18ca8 <+236>: bl     0x4ffa4                   ; CMS_final
    0x103a18cac <+240>: cbnz   w0, 0x50cdc               ; <+288>
    0x103a18cb0 <+244>: b      0x50cd0                   ; <+276>
    0x103a18cb4 <+248>: adrp   x3, 329
    0x103a18cb8 <+252>: add    x3, x3, #0xec6            ; =0xec6 
    0x103a18cbc <+256>: mov    w0, #0x2e
    0x103a18cc0 <+260>: mov    w1, #0x94
    0x103a18cc4 <+264>: mov    w2, #0x41
    0x103a18cc8 <+268>: mov    w4, #0x1d7
    0x103a18ccc <+272>: bl     0x8ebb8                   ; ERR_put_error
    0x103a18cd0 <+276>: mov    x0, x19
    0x103a18cd4 <+280>: bl     0x4c368                   ; CMS_ContentInfo_free
    0x103a18cd8 <+284>: mov    x19, #0x0
    0x103a18cdc <+288>: mov    x0, x19
    0x103a18ce0 <+292>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x30]
    0x103a18ce4 <+296>: ldp    x20, x19, [sp, #0x20]
    0x103a18ce8 <+300>: ldp    x22, x21, [sp, #0x10]
    0x103a18cec <+304>: ldp    x24, x23, [sp], #0x40
    0x103a18cf0 <+308>: ret    
    0x103a18cf4 <+312>: adrp   x3, 329
    0x103a18cf8 <+316>: add    x3, x3, #0xec6            ; =0xec6 
    0x103a18cfc <+320>: mov    w0, #0x2e
    0x103a18d00 <+324>: mov    w1, #0x94
    0x103a18d04 <+328>: mov    w2, #0x63
    0x103a18d08 <+332>: mov    w4, #0x1c3
    0x103a18d0c <+336>: b      0x50ccc                   ; <+272>
```

```
libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_rwlock_wrlock:
->  0x1ef12538c <+0>:   ldr    x8, [x0]
    0x1ef125390 <+4>:   mov    w9, #0x4c4b
    0x1ef125394 <+8>:   movk   w9, #0x5257, lsl #16
    0x1ef125398 <+12>:  cmp    x8, x9
    0x1ef12539c <+16>:  b.ne   0x1ef125414               ; <+136>
    0x1ef1253a0 <+20>:  add    x8, x0, #0x2f             ; =0x2f 
    0x1ef1253a4 <+24>:  and    x8, x8, #0xfffffffffffffff0
    0x1ef1253a8 <+28>:  ldr    x9, [x8]
    0x1ef1253ac <+32>:  tbnz   w9, #0x1, 0x1ef125414     ; <+136>
    0x1ef1253b0 <+36>:  mov    w10, #0x83
    0x1ef1253b4 <+40>:  mov    x11, #0x10000000000
    0x1ef1253b8 <+44>:  mov    x12, x9
    0x1ef1253bc <+48>:  tbz    w9, #0x6, 0x1ef125414     ; <+136>
    0x1ef1253c0 <+52>:  and    x13, x12, #0xffffffff00000000
    0x1ef1253c4 <+56>:  mov    w14, w9
    0x1ef1253c8 <+60>:  orr    x13, x13, x14
    0x1ef1253cc <+64>:  bfxil  w9, w10, #0, #8
    0x1ef1253d0 <+68>:  add    w9, w9, #0x100            ; =0x100 
    0x1ef1253d4 <+72>:  add    x12, x12, x11
    0x1ef1253d8 <+76>:  and    x12, x12, #0xffffffff00000000
    0x1ef1253dc <+80>:  orr    x12, x12, x9
    0x1ef1253e0 <+84>:  mov    x9, x13
    0x1ef1253e4 <+88>:  casa   x9, x12, [x8]
    0x1ef1253e8 <+92>:  mov    x12, x9
    0x1ef1253ec <+96>:  cmp    x9, x13
    0x1ef1253f0 <+100>: b.ne   0x1ef1253bc               ; <+48>
    0x1ef1253f4 <+104>: add    x8, x0, #0x1f             ; =0x1f 
    0x1ef1253f8 <+108>: and    x8, x8, #0xfffffffffffffff8
    0x1ef1253fc <+112>: mrs    x9, TPIDRRO_EL0
    0x1ef125400 <+116>: and    x9, x9, #0xfffffffffffffff8
    0x1ef125404 <+120>: ldur   x9, [x9, #-0x8]
    0x1ef125408 <+124>: str    x9, [x8]
    0x1ef12540c <+128>: mov    w0, #0x0
    0x1ef125410 <+132>: ret    
    0x1ef125414 <+136>: mov    w1, #0x0
    0x1ef125418 <+140>: mov    w2, #0x0
    0x1ef12541c <+144>: b      0x1ef124e30               ; _pthread_rwlock_lock_slow
```

Comment: I may be able to tell you what's happening, though I don't know why.  The "address" in your error message is actually ASCII code for some text (the word "sequence" backwards).  That suggests you might have a problem with a data structure having a string where a pointer to a string is expected.  Does this crash in the debugger so that you can get a stack trace?

Comment: This doesn't crash in the debugger. I do get output from the main thread when it crashes which I have updated the post with.

Comment: I also noticed that I had Address Santizer and Zombie objects on in the Xcode scheme. When I turn those off I don't run into any issues. Weird.

Comment: Still seems unsable at times. Notably when working with the resultant string.